# REGXP for MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, select, mariadb

To make this as quick as possible I have the following string

```
SIP/5106-0000235f
```

And I want to catch only the part after the SIP/ until the - so in this case

```
5106
```

I have made a few tries but always end up wrong.

If anyone could help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? What regexs have you tried so far? Is this format consistent? You could use `replace` for the `SIP/` then `substr` with `locate` for the `-`. to get the integer between. It wouldn't verify there was an integer though.

Comment: I don't know much about mysql. In case it supports positive lookaheads this pattern should work:
(?<=SIP/)([0-9]+)(?=-)

Comment: the mysql veriosn is mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.21-MariaDB , the closest mach I have is \SIP\/(.*)(.*?)\- , I would relly like for you to explain teh substr and locate method

Comment: So it is mariadb, not mysql. Consult https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp/ 10.2 looks like it uses PCRE so should be able to use lookaheads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with *Non-Regex* solution. You can try using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('SIP/5106-0000235F', 'SIP/', -1),'-', 1)
```

*Assumption : `SIP/` & `-` will appear only once as provided in the sample*

Comment: Thanks it was the perfect solution for this case

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(mycol, '^SIP/([^-]+).*$', '\\1')
```